# AC circuit voltages and currents

Tags: voltage, ac, homework

I have this circuit:

[image]

Have I done everything correctly? I cannot find my mistake. Help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake?

Comment: I don't know. I just find odd that for the loop AB voltage follows the current while in both i1 and i2 current follows the  voltage.

Comment: Have you tried simulating this? It should be easy enough to verify, either in `.TRAN` with a fixed sine (but more typing for `.MEAS` or finding with cursors), or in `.AC` with a list of one frequency (e.g. `.ac list 0.3183`). (edit: just tested it and it looks fine, save roundigs & co).

Comment: You can check this yourself. Calculate the voltage across each element and make sure that KVL holds.

Comment: I know there has been some history, but except for the (fairly common) "check me" question, I think it's a bit too harsh to downvote to hell. `-1` would have been enough to let the OP know it's something wrong. There's also no brazen talking. @MissMulan By saying "*I can't find my mistake*" it's implied there is a mistake, and your comment says "I am not sure". You can easily verify your calculations with [wolfram](https://wolframalpha.com), or some SPICE simulation (for free on this site). You would have seen that the only errors are in the roundings.

Answer (score 3):

If \$X_C=-j/(2\pi f C)=-j ; f=1/\pi\$.

Looks Ok except for notation in future use a bigger DOT \$\cdot\$ or * so it doesn’t look like a “.”

In code, here I used \cdot and \$ at each end

Comment: XL = 1.2j  . XL-XC = (1.2-0.94)j = 0.26j

Comment: \$X_L=j ~2\pi f L=j2L \$=j1.2

Comment: @MissMulan already said `XL=1.2j`. There is a comma afterwards, so maybe it's hard to see. After the comma there is `XL-XC=...`, so there's no need to insist on this. Also, it's not `4.1`, it's `4*1`. I admit that the picture is a bit hard to see (with my eyes, at least).